# How do I #show property contents?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm looking to use #show to display the contents of a property. I've yet to find a simple explanation of the parameters needed. The goal is to print the contents of the property "member pronoun." This then will allow documents to refer to either "he" or "she."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the show parser function like below.

I assume you stored the `member pronoun` on a user page, you would use the users page name in your show query , you prefix the result property with a `?`

`{{#show: user:USERNAME |?member pronoun}}`

explanation:
`{{#show: <page> |?<property>}}`

Read more on the show query here:
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries#Parser_function_.23show